# Determining ring homomorphisms on Boolean ring of power set of some set

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $R=P(X)$, the collection of all subsets of $X$. For $A,B\in R$, define:

$$A+B=(A\cup B)-(A\cap B),$$
$$AB=A\cap B,$$

where $-$ represents complement. With these operations, $R$ becomes a Boolean ring. Let $V\in R$ be non-empty. Concider two maps $f,g: R\rightarrow R$ defined as
$$f:A\mapsto A\cap V,$$
$$g:A\mapsto A\cup V.$$

I have to determine which, if any, of these maps is a ring homomorphism. In the definition of homomorphism I handle, it is required that, for a homomorphism $h$, $h(1)=1$.

I have found that both functions are not homomorphisms, but I'm not quite sure of it as my proof is far from rigorous (and involves Venn-diagrams). Can someone please confirm/ disprove my beilef and maybe present a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (mostly) correct.  The map $g$ is never a homomorphism (given that $V$ is nonempty), and the map $f$ is never a homomorphism unless $V=X$.  Indeed, note that $\emptyset$ is the additive identity of $R$, and $g(\emptyset)=V$, so $g$ cannot be a homomorphism since $V\neq\emptyset$.  Similarly, $X$ is the multiplicative identity of $R$, and $f(X)=V$, so $f$ cannot be a homomorphism unless $V=X$.  If $V=X$, then $f$ *is* a homomorphism (I'll let you figure out why).

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! If $V=X$, then $f(A)=A\cap X=A$, resulting in the trivial homomorphism. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep (though I would call it the _identity_ homomorphism rather than the "trivial homomorphism").